# C++ Addon example unable to find the created module

Tags: c++, windows, node.js

[image: my error]Hey all I am trying to do the addon example located here http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html (Hello World). Everything seems to run fine until the final step. I recieve the error in the picuture I attached. [For this shot I even put everything hello.js and hello.node in same folder with no sucess). I point to the location of my hello.node, but I keep getting this error anyone have success with this example or more their own c++ add on??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like Java, not C++.

Comment: the addon is written in c++, for node.js... I can do everything except find the created module for some reason